# How to change default validation error messages on belongs_to field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 5, `belongs_to` relation becomes required as default and gives **Model must exist** message on every failed validation. I want to localize default messages on every `belongs_to` occurrence at once. For example ...

In my model:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  validates :author_date, presence: true
end
```

In my localization file:

```
en:
     activerecord:
       errors:
         blank: "can't be blank" # not showing on book.errors[:person]
```

In console:

```
book = Book.new
book.save
puts book.errors.to_json
>> {person: ["must exist"], :author_date: ["can't be blank"]}
```

How can I localize **must exist** messages in YML file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has key `required`, try:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        required: "custom required message"
```

Comment: it looks like `blank:` is the key for the `presence` validation and `required:` is the key for the validation automatically included with the `belongs_to` method.  Is there a list somewhere that incluedes these keys for all validations (ex. `uniqueness`, `inclusion`, etc.)?

Comment: Nevermind! I found it here :) https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation